# Why is awk sub/gsub just erasing matches?

Tags: awk

I'm using awk in a batch file on windows. For some reason sub/gsub is erasing matches, rather than replacing.  I'm pulling my hair out over this...Here's a sample line:

```
awk "{ gsub(/ZSection/, "Section"); print}" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
```

Result: "ZSection" is just gone in temp2.txt.  No "Section", anywhere.

I'm using sub/gsub in other scripts on my machine without issue, same syntax (I think? Unless I'm just going blind and/or insane).

What am I missing? Is it possible some other operation in the batch file is screwing with the functionality of sub/gsub? Help!

Answer (score 9):

this is your code, which doesn't work.

```
awk "{ gsub(/ZSection/, "Section"); print}" temp1.txt
```

This is the correct code:

```
awk '{ gsub(/ZSection/, "Section"); print}' temp1.txt
```

can you find the difference?

If we go a little deeper, your matched pattern was removed. because the **variable** `Section` was not set with any value. yes, here awk thinks the `Section` is a variable. If you want to prove it:

```
awk "{Section=555; gsub(/ZSection/, "Section"); print}" temp1.txt
awk "{Section=\"hello\"; gsub(/ZSection/, "Section"); print}" temp1.txt
```

check the output of above two lines, you will see.

the 2nd part of my answer just for explaining why the matches were removed. However we should quote the command correctly.

Comment: Good explanation. Deserves **+1**

Answer (score 7):

Your problem seems to be the same quotes for the script and for your replacement string. Substitute the outer pair with single quotes:

```
awk '{ gsub(/ZSection/, "Section"); print}' temp1.txt > temp2.txt
```

Comment: Yes and no...Did a search for "awk windows quotes" and saw that escape sequences are different.  The correct syntax is "{ gsub(/ZSection/, \"Section\"); print}".  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @wolfmason: Thank you. I tested it only in Linux. I've added the correct one for Windows to the answer. **EDIT**: Aggh, now realized that you added your own answer, so I will remove it from mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk "{ gsub(/ZSection/, \"Section\"); print}" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
```

Found another overflow question regarding quotes with awk in windows 7 (thanks to other posters for mentioning quotes, though their solutions didn't work).  The solution there suggested a syntax similar to  \""Section\"".  This worked, but it appears to be one more set of quotes than necessary for my script to work.  It's all in the slashes...